# Why do i get minus function error in cloud function node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I use bignumber in nodejs for cloud functions with firebase.I added BigNumber at the end thinking that it might help.

```
const BigNumber = require("bignumber.js").BigNumber;
let Price = new BigNumber(0);
let Fee = new BigNumber(0.15);
let FeePrice = new BigNumber(0);
let TotalPrice = new BigNumber(0);
const priceValue = json["value"];
Price = new BigNumber(priceValue);
FeePrice = Price.times(Fee).toFormat(2, 6);
TotalPrice = Price.minus(FeePrice);
```

I get this error in Cloud Function Log TypeError:

> Price.minus is not a function

Comment: Can I know what is `json` in your `Price = json["value"]` line?

Comment: its a json object

Comment: So you're changing `Price` from `BigNumber` to some JSON object value, which means it is no longer BigNumber's instance.

Comment: you are right. i have updated my code and deployed again but i still get the same error

Comment: can you tell output of `typeof priceValue` ?

Comment: Price output is 25.40 and FeePrice is 2.76

Comment: Then it should work and try to convert priceValue to `Number()`

Comment: Same error. I also tried TotalPrice = BigNumber(Price).minus(BigNumber(FeePrice)); and TotalPrice = Price; TotalPrice = TotalPrice.minus(FeePrice); and i got same error. I uninstall bignumber and install it again and same error.

Comment: TripFunction
Price: 25.40
2:05:09.243 pm
TripFunction
feePrice: 2.76
2:05:09.245 pm
TripFunction
catch error: TypeError: Price.minus is not a function

Comment: Can you check if Price is instanceof BigNumber or not? if yes then can you console.dir `Price`?

Comment: TripFunction. 'Price: 25.40'  this is the output for console.dir("Price: " + Price);

Comment: so typeof is a string actually.

Comment: space x launch is in 12 minutes :)

Comment: they cancelled because of the weather.

Comment: thank you. it works now. i did TotalPrice = new BigNumber(Price).minus(FeePrice);

Comment: i'm new to node and js and i didn't know u can do console typeof

Comment: okay have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `typeof Price` might be a string. So it needs to be converted to `BigNumber`.
You can use `TotalPrice` with BigNumber static method itself. (thanks to your comment replies)

```js
TotalPrice = new BigNumber(Price).minus(FeePrice);
```